# How to create artifact from a build in Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins

i'm discovring Jenkins and i set a new build for my project and i want to archive the build if it is a successuful build. How should  do to create artifact to reference it in the step of post build?

Thanks

Comment: When you say archive, you mean to store it within Jenkins or upload to some external artifacts manager?

Comment: thanks for responding, i want to create artifcat after a build success , how i do it? then to store it within jenkins.

Comment: When you are building a Jenkins job, you will generate some artifacts, say a .jar or .dll file. Once this is done, I assume your job is a success. The build is itself an "artifact" and will be stored in Jenkins job's workspace.

Comment: Thank you, i'm building a .net solution, how can i configure artificat as a .zip file ? in build command line i set /p:Configuration=Release /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true and in the actions after build section\file to archive i set  
**/* pattern but it seems to generate java / .jar files  !! :(

Comment: What kind of Jenkins pipeline (declarative/scripted) are you using? Can you share it here?

Comment: Post the details of jenkins pipeline/screenshot of job configuration by editing the Question. This will help in understanding it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i installed File Operations plugin, i added file zip step in the buid, i set the folder to zip. Then i added a step after buid (archive artifact) and i set file to archive folder\myProject.zip. and launched a build. It works ! Thanks for all